# Yii2 Trailing Slashes in URL is breaking the route

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, yii-url-manager

I configured UrlManager in a project and It was working the way I wanted. 
Now i tried to add a content whose name contains a trailing slash but i get an error 404 (Object not found).

**For example:** 
www.test.com/article/detail/id_of_article/title_of_article

title_of_article = **People are ...**  => **Work**

title_of_article = **1/3 of People are ...**  => **Doesn't Work (Object not Found)**

The Trailing Slash is breaking the Url although it is encoded in **%2F**

This is how i create url:

```
Html::a(Html::encode($model->title), 
        ['article/detail', 'id' => $model->id, 'title' => $model->title])
```

I don't really know how I can deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For This , the best solution is to use **slug names**.

Instead of `id` and `title`, take one more field called `slug_name` in your database.

On Add or update of any record generate slug name and store in db.

For generating slug name, you can use custom function as below.

```
public function getSlugName($id,$title)
  {
    $slug=$id;
    if(isset($title) && $title!=null)
    {
      // remove all spacea
      $slug.='-'.str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($title)); 
    }
    $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $slug); // Removes special chars.
    $slug=str_replace(array('--'), '-', $slug); // remove multiple --
    return $slug;
  }
```

This function will return you uniq name. So you can use it in url.

This is also help in SEO.

Comment: This is a good idea. It s true it  will change the title name a litte bit by removing special chars, but it is an good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need  `URL normalization`

> Since version 2.0.10 UrlManager can be configured to use UrlNormalizer
>   for dealing with variations of the same URL, for example with and
>   without a trailing slash.

NB by default UrlManager::$normalizer is disabled. You need to explicitly configure it in order to enable URL normalization.

see how here  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-normalization

Comment: @stfsngue : you mean it can be seen as duplicated content?

Answer (score 0):

There is an encodeParams property of UrlRule. Please try with that.